# $n$ couples sitting around a table. Let $X$ be the number of couples that sits next to each other.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Alright, so we have $n$ couples sitting around a table, randomly. Hence, $|\Omega|=(2n-1)!$

Let $X$= number of couples that sits next to each other.

I was asked to find $\sigma^2(X)$ and it took me some time.

But, surprisingly (for me, anyway), i discovered that $X$ is actualy a Bernouli variable. Meaning, $X$~$B(2n,\, \frac{1}{2n-1})$.

And of course that makes $\sigma^2(X)$ **much** easier to calculate.

But i still don't get the idea of that.

I know that if a random variable $Y$ has a Bernouli distribution with the parameters $n,p$, then $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of a single success.

How would you describe $X$ so that it'll all make sense?

I can see that $X$ has $2n$ "trials", but how would you describe a trial in here?

Also, i see that $p=\frac{1}{2n-1}$. It looks like that's the probability of $1$ couple to sit together, when the husband in the left-side and the wife in the right-side, but it doesn't seem right when we have $2n$ "trials", knowing there are $n$ couples and not $2n$.

Hope you understood my point. I'd be happy to hear your perspective!

Comment: Probability of a couple seated together is $\frac{2}{2n-1}$ so calculation of expectation is straightforward. For calculating variance, you will need to use covariance.

Comment: yeah, i know how to calculate the variance. My question was: How is that $X$~$B(2n, \frac{1}{2n-1})$?


And you're right, i was mistaken. I meant that $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ is the probability that some guy will sit in the right-side of his wife. Thanks for notice. i edited it.

Comment: as we know, if $Y$~$B(n, p)$, then it's straightforward that $\sigma^2(Y)=np(1-p)$.

And as you see in here, if $X$~$B(2n, \frac{1}{2n-1})$, then: $\sigma^2(X)=2n*\frac{1}{2n-1}*(1-\frac{1}{2n-1})=\frac{4n^2-4n}{4n^2-4n+1}$, which is exactly what you'll get if you'll calculate the variance with covariance like you suggested.

Comment: OK I get it. So in a way your question is if it is not $Y~$ ~ $~B(n, p)$, why it gives the correct answer.

Comment: yeah, exactly. i can't find an explanation...